# Photobromination of cyclohexene

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, radicals

During bromination of cyclohexene in the presence of hv via free radical mechanism, there are two allylic carbons. Why does the major product have only one Br an not a Br on either side of double bond.

Comment: There are way more $\cdot$H than there are $\cdot$Br, This makes the *major* product the monobrominated one.

Comment: Depends on how much Bromine is used. Use an excess and you get di-bromo product

Comment: It is also worth noting that for $\ce{Br2}$, electrophilic addition to the pi bond is much faster than the allylic radical bromination. Dropwise addition of $\ce{Br2}$ to cyclohexene at room temperature in the near dark results in almost instantaneous decolorization of  bromine.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!. May i know why my post was downvoted ?